# can only use limited amount of methods on java sql

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it normal that if you declare a method on a jFrameView. You can only use few methods from the java.sql package?I'm trying to create a preparedStatement so that I could perform an insert query but I only got these:
[image]

Whereas if I use the connection object on a normal command line style java app. I get a bunch of methods available:

[image]

They're all under the same folder(package) where the jFrame/Form is. And the package.
Please help, I can't understand why its acting this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `conn` is not been declared as `java.sql.Connection`. You've declared it as `conc` which seems to be some homegrown class. Fix it accordingly. If it is supposed to be some sort of a connection manager, then you should rewrite that class that it has a method which **returns** a fullworthy `java.sql.Connection` so that you can use it further in your code.

This [basic tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) should get you started with approaching JDBC the proper way.